# how to get this bit work in pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

heyya all, well pdo is kinda new to me and i sure got no idea how to get this bit of code converted into pdo, if one of you could help me out in this would really be a great help

here is my code

```
$unique_ref_length = 8;    
        $unique_ref_found = false;  
        $possible_chars = "23456789BCDFGHJKMNPQRSTVWXYZ";  
        while (!$unique_ref_found) {  
              $unique_ref = "";    
            $i = 0;       
            while ($i < $unique_ref_length) {      
                $char = substr($possible_chars, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible_chars)-1), 1);            
                $unique_ref .= $char;            
                $i++;  
                  }      
        $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ref ='".$unique_ref."'";  
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error().' '.$query);  
        if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {        
            $unique_ref_found = true;        
        }    
    } 
    $ref = $unique_ref;
```

Comment: Try something and you will get help with it. Don't try at all => Get no help here.

Comment: Have you first created an instance of PDO? You might be interested in reading the [PDO documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to begin with, and show us what you've produced so far.

Comment: Read [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info). Try something.If you have problems come back with  a proper [**question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ref ='".$unique_ref."'";  
         $stm = $db->prepare($query );
   $stm->execute();
        if ( $row = $stm->rowCount()==0) {        
            $unique_ref_found = true;        
        }    

did this but no result

Answer (score -2):

its fixed nevermind and thanks

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE token ='".$unique_ref."'";  
             $stm = $db->prepare($qry);
             $stm->execute();
                if ( $row = $stm->rowCount()==0) {        
                    $unique_ref_found = true;        
                }
```

Comment: No it's not, without a bindable parameter that won't prepare anything. You're sending an unsanitised string to your database.  If that's the intent then you might as well take out the prepare line. It's not doing anything.  Use $db->exec instead.